# How to parse JSON Array in listview in android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse JSON `Array` and display result in `listview`. I have already ask in this community but didn't get helpful answer. Please give me code for this JSON.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "city_id": "1",
    "city_name": "Noida"
},
{
    "city_id": "2",
    "city_name": "Delhi"
},
{
    "city_id": "3",
    "city_name": "Gaziyabad"
},
{
    "city_id": "4",
    "city_name": "Gurgaon"
},
{
    "city_id": "5",
    "city_name": "Gr. Noida"
}]
```

**URL**

http://14.140.200.186/Hospital/newget_city.php

please help

Comment: what is your listview looklike?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json Parsing in Android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819273/json-parsing-in-android-application)

Comment: The question is really broad. You should address one issue at a time. Are you facing issues in Fetching the JSON, parsing the JSON or populating the ListView? Start with one, learn how to do it, and if you face issues, post your question here, with the code that doesn't work at your end.

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh nothing is going in listview

Comment: @Shamas i want to simply show cities in listview from the url when i trying this nothig is going in listview i have already post the locat and code click on the link you can see:-         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170183/logcat-error-in-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment58058833_35170183

Comment: @Satyamrathore: which library are you using for json parsing ?

Comment: @Satyamrathore .... It was yours previous same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35721219/3946958 with Tom user name.. Did you not get proper solution yet??Let me know where did u stuck??

Comment: this question has been solved

Comment: Link given by you is asking that when click on cityname then id of the city should be store in database table, table already has city_id and all the id of all cities should be store in city_id on clicking city. have you got it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the question is too broad, just to give the approach I would take.

1. Build the model class in this case:  City
2. I would advise using retrofit(http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for the network call, so build the interface
3. Make the network call
4. Add the retrieved results in a recyclerview adapter

Answer (score 0):

Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) can do the json parsing job for you. Its easy to integrate and handy to parse json data. You simply need to create a class containing city_id and city_name.

City.java

```
public class City {

    private String city_id;
    private String city_name;

    public City() {

    }

    public String getCityId() {
        return city_id;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return city_name;
    }
}
```

Now add another class. E.g. CityList.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class CityList {

    private List<City> cityList;

    public CityList() {
    }

    public List<City> getCityList() {
        return cityList;
    }

}
```

Now from json string, parse the data into the CityList class.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
CityList myCityList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, CityList.class);
```

Add the gradle dependency for Gson in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```