# How to return the id of selected item of listview

Tags: android, spinner

Hello friends i am new to android and i am learning about android programming. I am working with my friends. I have web service from which i am showing list of cities in listview now my friend give me task that is  when i will click on city then id of that city return me so i don't how to do so please anybody can help me to do so.

```
public class CityNameActivity extends ListActivity{
private TextView displayText;
ListView list;



private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get Cities JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/Hospital/get_city.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CITIES = "Cities";
private static final String TAG_ID = "city_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "city_name";
// Cities JSONArray
JSONArray Cities = null;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> citylist;

//ArrayList<String> citylist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cityname_activity_main);

    ListView listView=getListView();

    citylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

          new GetCities().execute();
}



/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetCities extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CityNameActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CITIES);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Cities.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Cities.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> Cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Cities.put(TAG_ID, id);

                    Cities.put(TAG_NAME, name);



                    // adding contact to Cities list
                    citylist.add(Cities);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**`enter code here`
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CityNameActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.city_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);





    }
}}
```

cityname_mai_activity.xml

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select City"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"/>
```

city_list_item:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: please help i am waiting for any reply

Comment: you need to add clickListener in your RecyclerView item layout. There you can get the information that you passed in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Spinner` like these below:

```
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);  


    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_item,ARRAYLIST_DATA_HERE);  
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item); 

    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
    spin.setAdapter(aa); 

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

               String items=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
               Log.i("Selected item : ",items);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    return true;
```

Use the spinner_item **xml**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BAB7BA"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: @Tom ... I am able to implement the above code in yours code..I want that ,  first you should have try...and if you getting any problem after that ,  i will able to help you..

Comment: oh sorry i was not here just i came try your suggestion sorry for that. i want to know that are you there?

Comment: ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.city_list_item,citylist); in this line i am getting error that is can not reslove constructor and in this line  spin.setAdapter(aa); spin can not reslove

Comment: i wrote this  ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.city_list_item,citylist);
   aa.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.city_list_item);

   //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
   spin.setAdapter(aa);

Comment: i tried this listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.city_list_item,citylist); but now getActivity cannot reslove

Comment: @Tom ... Why are you not using the Activity instead of ListActivity .Follow some steps like:----First make the spinner in yours XML file than use the Activity OR Fragment to implement, yours spinner...Changes these , and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @ Ravindra Kushwaha thanks for reply i working my friend this task i will try later but right now he said that cities which you will select then id of the city return me can you help me to do this my code is already above so please help to do so hope you understand

Comment: i have edit my question can you reply according to this

Comment: @Tom ... Why are you not understanding brother that, if you want to use the Spinner than, we have to first create spinner in the XML not listview...So create the spinner and find the id by findViewbyId() method and than use my above code...What i have said ealier that, you can use the Simple activity to perform yours opertion, but you did not gettng me :( , So try thing simple than it will automatically simple for you :) ...All the best

Comment: i tried i am getting error  spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); in this red line showing below of this and String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); in this spinner can not resolve  and return true; is also getting red line

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `On Click Listener` for your `ListView` ?? I think that will solve your problem.. Use `onClikcListener's` on `ItemClick` event which will give you position and based on that position you can get item from your `Arraylist` which will give you `id` from that..

Comment: i tried this but it is showing id for me in toast but i want to send my friend's table

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {

    Map<String, String> tempHashmap =  (Map<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String tagName = tempHashmap.get(TAG_NAME);
    System.out.println("tagname" + tagName);
    String tagId = (String)cityListWithId.get(tagName);

    System.out.println("tagId" + tagId);


//    Toast.makeText(CityNameActivity.this, tagId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
  });

Comment: You gave written toast code that's why it's showing you toast.. BTW what's friends table

Comment: i dont want to show i have commented this in friends table there are there are two column of city_name and city_id now he want that when i will click on ctiyname then id of that city should be shown in city_id column

Comment: try citylist.get(position); instead of parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: first of all did you understand what am i asking?

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {


    Map<String, String> tempHashmap =  (Map<String, String>)
      citylist.get(position);
    String tagName = tempHashmap.get(TAG_NAME);
   System.out.println("tagname" + tagName);
    String tagId = (String)cityListWithId.get(tagName);

    System.out.println("tagId" + tagId);

    Log.d("Clicked item id", " " + id);

Comment: Can you just post whole code? in Code format or edit you question before.. What I understood is you want city id onclick of your list view.. And than you want to send the same to your friend's table

Comment: i have posted my whole code in question and in friend's table has only city_id column and i repeat that when i click on city name then id of that city should be store in city_id. I have webservice in which i have city_name and city_id i have been shown cityname in listview now want to do as i asked hope you got my point